# Get Apache Document Root from command line execution (No browser)

Tags: php, url, command-line

Not sure if the title is correct, Please edit if you think of a better one.

I have a XMLRPC service that I call from the command line. It's using Zend framework.

the client looks like this:

$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://hostname/path/to/xmlrpc.server.php');

The file is located:

```
/var/www/html/path/to/xmlrpc.server.php
```

I have it hard coded now but wanted to populate the 'path/to/' generically.

I've tried:

```
function url(){
  $protocol = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https" : "http";
  return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

echo url();
```

Note: None of the $_SERVER options returned what I needed

but executing this from the command line gives me:

```
http://
```

Also `getcwd()` give me:

```
 /var/www/html/path/to
```

How can I get:

```
http://path/to
```

Any thoughts?

The reason I would like this is if the project needs to change directories it should auto configure. Example:

If I move the project here:

```
/var/www/html/path/to/another/location
```

or here:

```
/var/www/public_html/path/to/another/location
```

or even here:

```
/path/to/document/root/path/to/another/location
```

I should get:

```
http://hostname/path/to/another/location
```

Thanks for any help

UPDATE:

I tried this but still not working as expected:

```
$hostname = `hostname`;
echo 'http://'.trim($hostname).'/'.basename(getcwd())."\n";
```

Comment: Why are you using an absolute URL (`http://examle.com/path/to/another/location/something`) rather than a relative URL (`something`) and just trusting the browser to supply the rest?

Comment: I'm not accessing this from the browser. I wanted to generate the location where this can be accessed by the browser from the command line.

Comment: As you are not sending the request from Apache I doubt that there is any solution apart from scanning the configuration file for the document root.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple Answer: You can't.

As NikiC already stated in his comment to your question, invoking the script from the command line implies that there is no notion of a web server context available. The concept of a 'hostname' and a 'document root' only exist in the web server context, and are based on the configuration of the server. There is nothing in your `/var/www/something` directory that says 'Hey, I am a document root'.

To illustrate, assume you have an Apache configured with two vhosts, using two document roots:

- vhost A, using `/var/www/top-docroot`
- vhost B, using `/var/www/top-docroot/nested-docroot`.

Your script is located at:

`/var/www/top-docroot/nested-docroot/path/to/xmlrpc.server.php`

What path should your script use, when invoked from the command line?

- vhost A would call for `nested-docroot/path/to/xmlrpc.server.php`
- vhost B would call for `path/to/xmlrpc.server.php`

While this is a pretty contrived example, it should still demonstrate the point that a document root can only be reliably determined in the context of a web server request, as it is read from configuration.

So when invoked from the command line, all your script could do would be to try to get the information from the web server configuration (which has no reliable place either), or to use some heuristics, such as assuming the common convention of document roots residing under `/var/www`. Both methods would be pretty unreliable, and you are probably better of sticking to hard coded values (or passing the information as a parameter on invocation).

Comment: So the only way to get the DOC ROOT/Hostname is to use a web server (Apache)?

Comment: Basically yes, but more precisely: The only way to _have_ a Doc Root/Hostname is in the context of a web server - the web server defines those, and thus is the only real source that knows about them (via its configuration).

Comment: So would there be another way to find all the hosts that apache will server (Virtual hosts) from the command line? maybe parsing the /etc/hosts file and then using cURL to ping the sites? If 200 status could I get a DOC ROOT that way? I know is a bit of a hack

Comment: or instead of /etc/hosts maybe /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: I even thought about self configuring Apache, generate all the conf files and execute all the apache command. Still a hack but might work

Comment: '/etc/hosts' has nothing to do with your web server configuration - it is just a local ip-address<>hostname mapping that allows you to define custom mappings that can not be resolved via DNS (or override a DNS entry). The hosts you serve are defined in the web servers configuration, which you _could_ parse from your script. But there are many different places where these configurations can reside, depending on the web server, your server OS and distro, etc...

Comment: ... e.g. if you are on a Debian/Ubuntu style system, parsing the entries in '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled' would work, but only as long as you don't move to a different style distro/system (and no one circumvents the default mechanism by e.g. adding a vhost directly in httpd.conf).

Comment: For now we are running Ubuntu so I'm happy with /etc/apache2/sites-enabled, No Windows and I don't think we are changing anytime soon. What do you think about auto configuring Apache to add a new Virtual Host for my XMLRPC service. Im leaning towards this option I think unless someone has any hurdles that might block it

Comment: BTW +1 for all the help/insight

Comment: Concerning auto configuration of Apache to dynamically add new vhosts, I see no obvious hurdle, but this depends a lot on your use case/circumstances - I guess this is a separate discussion aimed more at the admin side of things (or release/build management).

Comment: `grep -irh '^[^#]*DocumentRoot' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ | awk '{print $2}' | sort -u` would probably get you a list of documentroot directories from standard virtualhosts in ubuntu, barring things like Apache's [mass virtualhosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` get you the path you need? As I understand it this should get you the absolute path when requested through the webserver, which I assume you're doing judging by the http url in your post. When called through the php command line it could be a relative path, which should be relative to cwd(). More info [here](http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/current_file_path.php)

Comment: I get no data for any of the $_SERVER variable when called from CLI.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/getcwd

Works perfectly when you're running a CLI app. Just make sure you know in which subdirectory you're running the application from and apply something with dirname() accordingly.

For example, if your docroot is set to: /var/www and your CLI app is inside /var/www/jobs/foobar/myapp.php, you could do something like this:

Method 1:

```
// Store the current docroot
$cwd = getcwd(); 
// Change directory and get the absolute path using getcwd again.
chdir($cwd . '/../../'); 
$docroot = getcwd();
// Restore the original cwd.
chdir($cwd);
```

Method 2:

```
// Get absolute path of docroot:
$docroot = dirname(getcwd() . '/../../');
```

Comment: Instead of changing the dir twice you should be able to use `realpath()` as well.

Comment: getcwd() is extremely dangerous, it changed behavior after PHP4. After PHP5, it will give you the path of the **parent script** not the included script. And for CLI, it will return you your current working directory (PWD). So always use dirname(__FILE__) which has compatibility and returns the sub-script directory statically everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I always use these below and they work everywhere, either be called from CLI or any script or when being included under sub script(s):

```
// Application Paths:
echo "<br>appPath:".$appPath = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "<br>appParent:".$appParent = dirname($appPath);
echo "<br>appGrandParent:".$appGrandParent = dirname($appParent);
```

Answer (score -1):

This might be sort of a hack job, but i just tried it and it worked nicely:

```
$fullPath = dirname(__FILE__);
$wwwRoot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
$list = explode($wwwRoot, $fullPath);

echo $list[1];
```

Like I said, I'm sure it's far from perfect; but it's a start!

Comment: I get 'Warning: explode(): Empty delimiter. in ...' are you executing this from the command line?

Comment: You must be trying to run 'php file.php' from command line, correct?