# php get document root of server via CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Simply, I want to get `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from the command line using PHP.

The PHP docs state:

> You may or may not find any of the following elements in $_SERVER. Note that few, if any, of these will be available (or indeed have any meaning) if running PHP on the command line.

Is there a known alternative to achieve the result? Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, but I can't find anything on this specific question.

Comment: No, not without trying to recreate apache's server startup/config parsing system. It'd be highly non-trivial anyways, especially if Apache's serving up MULTIPLE sites - exactly how could the script figure out WHICH virtualhost's doc root should be used?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I did find this question which highlights what you've just said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361355/get-apache-document-root-from-command-line-execution-no-browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$pwd = getenv('PWD');   // Current directory
$home = getenv('HOME'); // Home user directory
```

You can see more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788365/999820).