# $_SERVER document root in CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

In `CLI $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not working. How can I fix this? Is there any other option available. I cannot use relative paths, because files are in various directories.

Comment: Is not working? What is the output you expected and what is your current output? Error messages?

Comment: for those who are unaware, on command line, there is a blank answer for document root because it is not defined.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$_SERVER contains headers which won't be available in the CLI.  The web server defines the document root. In the CLI, you aren't using a web server, so there is no document root.

You can try to rely on environmental variables, assuming they are set by your shell.

For instance, `PWD` represents the current directory and `HOME` represents the user's home directory.

```
$pwd = getenv('PWD');
$home = getenv('HOME');
```

You can also use `__FILE__` or `__DIR__` [**magic constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) to try and depict the path you are currently in.

Comment: Might be old but this was a massive help. In my case, \_\_DIR\_\_ gave me the right path for both HTTP and CLI, allowing the same script to run for both.

Comment: this question and answer is still valid in fall 2019 (quite accurate)

Comment: This post helped me in my symfony project using PHP 8.1.11. I had to start two folders higher to add a log file, so I used a derivative. dirname(__DIR__, 2)."/var/log/Currency-FX-log".