# Ajax not call when web-hook send some event

Tags: php, ajax, webhooks

I have two pages one is workflow.php where web-hook send some data, after receiving data I want to send this data to other page because of some reason which is aq.php

workflow.php

```
<?
$cmd = 'echo "hii3" > debug2.log';
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd)."</pre>";
$cmd1 = 'echo '.$_POST['action'].' >> debug2.log';
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd1)."</pre>";
$cmd2 = 'echo ' .$_POST['id'].' >> debug2.log';
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd2)."</pre>";
$id=$_POST['id'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(
function() {


var id= '<?php echo $id ;?>';
$.ajax({
    url: "http://35.160.133.54/bitrix/aq.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {id : id},
                    success: function(data){


                                        }
                    }); 




});
</script>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

aq.php

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("AQ");

if($_POST)
{
$cmd = "echo ".$_POST['id']." > debug5.log";
echo "<pre>".shell_exec($cmd)."</pre>";
}

?><?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

When I run workflow.php manually then its run the aq.php file.But when web-hook send some data to workflow.php its not run aq.php

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: how I can see ajax response,because data send to the workflow.php when some one book a demo to acuity software and my code is on in different server.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web-hook is not a Browser... so what ever you do in your browser will work because your browser is executing the JavaScript (the Ajax call). A web-hook only doing the (GET/POST) request, what ever you respond **will NOT be executed**!
If you want do solve this you have to find an other way.

For example if you have the privilege on your sever to execute [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) you can simulate the Ajax request.

```
'curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -d "id":' . $id .' http://35.160.133.54/bitrix/aq.php'
```

Or you use the PHP version:

```
<?php                                                              
    $data_string = json_encode(array("id" => $id)); 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://35.160.133.54/bitrix/aq.php");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I debug my code then I realise if i include require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php"); then my code is not execute,but this require file present that location.please suggest

Comment: When I run this code manually then the code is running with required file,but when acuity software send some data to my page i.e workflow.php that time code is not executing.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788048/server-document-root-in-cli